# Installing Apache Spark on Windows

Tags: apache-spark

I need to install [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) on a Windows machine. According to the documentation I should have sbt installed on my machine and also override its default options to use a maximum of 2G of RAM.

After trying a lot I decided to choose maven instead (I overrided the default options to use 512MB) and I could run `mvn compile` that started to download some dependencies until it reached Zinc server. It said Zinc server didn`t run on port 8080 and maven failed the build.

Do I need to install the Zinc server locally and add it to Windows path? Can I compile my project without the server?

Comment: You do not need zinc at all to build Spark. It just speeds up incremental builds.

Comment: See also more up-to-date advice at [How to set up Spark on Windows? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481325/how-to-set-up-spark-on-windows)

Comment: Do you really have to build Spark from source? You can install pre-built packages, too.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started learning Apache Spark so I might be far from the valid answer. It worked for me on Mac OS X so your millage may vary.

The build process is described in [Building](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/):

> Spark uses Simple Build Tool, which is bundled with it. To compile the
>   code, go into the top-level Spark directory and run
>
> ```
> sbt/sbt assembly
> ```

I've not changed the default build settings to do the assembly.

Yesterday's build from the sources:

```
jacek:~/oss/spark
$ sbt/sbt assembly
...
[success] Total time: 3632 s, completed May 6, 2014 2:39:07 AM
```

Today's build from the sources with some environment variables that add few other modules to the final assembly:

```
jacek:~/oss/spark
$ SPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.4.0 SPARK_YARN=true SPARK_HIVE=true sbt/sbt assembly
...
[success] Total time: 4564 s, completed May 7, 2014 1:49:56 AM
```

Comment: i guess you could run it on mac OS because that mac machines have high config (e.g. high RAM) but as i said before i get the jvm memory error and i guess it is because of my ram (i have 2Gig RAM installed on my machine) but i colulden`t find any documents about minimum RAM requirments of SPARK.

Comment: Use sbt and in the cmd do `set SBT_OPTS=-Xmx1g` and then execute `sbt/sbt assembly`. Add the stacktrace/error to your question when it happens. Stay away from maven from the moment as I can help more - I know it better than maven for Scala builds.