# Running apache Spark on windows

Tags: windows, apache-spark, build

I am trying to run apache spark on windows . Can someone give me a step by step instruction to do this . I have downloaded spark ,sbt and scala . Can some one give step by step  . I want to run this as a standalone program

Comment: [Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/)

Comment: For a more recent version (Spark-2.x.x) you can consider this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39232917/2766382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using building with sbt approach, then you'll need git also.
Install Scala, sbt and git on your machine. Download Spark source code and run following command

```
sbt assembly
```

In case,if you use prebuilt release,Here is the step by step process:
[How to run Apache Spark on Windows7 in standalone mode](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the step by step guide [Here](https://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/How_to_build_SPARK_on_Windows). in the sigmoidanalytics site. But it is different for different versions of the spark.

If you are Trying to use eclipse to built a standalone application using maven spark dependency you have to install cygwin and add cygwin/bin to your path because Spark uses linux command  " **ls** " for finding the file permission.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're trying to run. If trying to run Spark Shell, please follow instructions from 
http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html

If trying to run your own spark job, create a simple application in (either JAVA/SCALA/Python). I use Scala for development, so in Scala include folliwing libs:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.0",
```

And then write a simple main method to test it :

```
 object MainProcessorJob extends App {
 private val applicationName = "FileProcessor"
 private val cores = "local[5]"
 private val intervalSecs = 1
 start()
 def start(): Unit = {
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf(true)
 val sparkContext = new SparkContext(cores, applicationName, sparkConf)
 ----------
}
```

You should be able to right click and run this in intelliJ / eclipse.