# Spark setup in windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-spark

Can anyone suggest me a good tutorial to set up spark in my machine which is remotely accessing other machine in which hadoop is installed .

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a client setup. The hadoop distribution you're planning to connect to may have a client setup in their docs. Like MapR has mapr-client.

Once that is in place, follow any of these to setup spark,

[How to set up Spark on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481325/how-to-set-up-spark-on-windows/39232917#39232917)

[Running apache Spark on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164182/running-apache-spark-on-windows)

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~shantas/Install_Spark_on_Windows10.pdf

Let me know if this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to develop with Spark using IntelliJ IDEA on your Windows. Create a SBT project where you can copy the next code on the build file, and it will download all the dependencies for you.

```
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
// grading libraries
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % "test"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.3",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.3",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.6.3"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-csv" % "1.4",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9",
  "com.univocity" % "univocity-parsers" % "1.5.1"
)
libraryDependencies +="com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0"
```

After that create a scala object, and begin developping. It is mainly for local development in Spark. Pay attention to the paths when reading or writing files.