# SparkContext not found on windows7

Tags: python, pyspark

I have install sparks for pyspark using the method mentioned in this link..

http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html

Now I am creating pyspark and trying to use "sc" variable.But I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

I tried to below variables

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '2g')
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name")
```

the error i am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\BIGDATA\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "D:\BIGDATA\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 272, in _ensure_initialized
    callsite.function, callsite.file, callsite.linenum))
ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by getOrCreate at D:\BIGDATA\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\..\python\pyspark\shell.py:43
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the following error:

> ValueError: **Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once;** existing
>   SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by getOrCreate
>   at
>   D:\BIGDATA\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin..\python\pyspark\shell.py:43

The source of this error seems to be a previous `SparkContext` which wasn't stopped.

Executing `sc.stop()` before trying to to create another `SparkContext` should solve the `multiple SparkContexts` error.

Some additional links for installing spark on Windows (from my experience some instructions are missing some details):

- I've used this answer when I've installed spark on my Windows7:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38735202/5088142
- https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html
- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-build-apache-spark-windows-step-anuj-bhatnagar