# Installing spark on windows 10 spark.hive.hiveSessionState

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
  ... 47 elided
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
  ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:169)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.scala:157)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
  ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
  ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:366)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:270)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
  ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:192)
  ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
  ... 85 more
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to

      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

I googled a lot but i was unable to get reason for this error SparkContext doesn't provide us with sc object which it usually provides.It even creates problem when i try to manually create object for SparkContext. I dont need hive in my project but how can i ignore this problem

Thanks in Advance for the help

Comment: Unless you have enough time and patience, stopping fiddling spark with windows would be the suggestion from my own experience. If you just want to learn how to use spark, get a Linux OS, it will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Did you installed winutils? Here is good link for instalation spark on windows. https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/apache-spark-installation-on-windows-10/

Comment: yeah i have installed winutills and also set path for it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved it. It required 777 permission on hive folder in tmp.

Just open the command prompt and run it as administrator and use the following command:

```
C:\hadoop\bin>winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive
```

It just solved all the errors.
Thanks for the help. The problem is solved

Comment: Haven't tried yet, but link to more info: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html

Comment: I am getting an error "ChangeFileModeByMask error (3): The system cannot find the path specified". Any idea why.

Answer (score 6):

if you download **spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7**, you have to download winutils.exe in folder **hadoop-2.7.1** of https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils.

do not forget to run "winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive" in CommandLine as Administrator, and in the correct hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it as follows:-
1. install the findspark 
  #pip install findspark
2. launch your jupyter notebook  ( and not as pyspark --master..)
3. include the following in your code:-

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql as sq

    sp= sq.SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("your-app-name").getOrCreate()
    sc=sp.sparkContext
```

Note: I have used spark 2.2.0 with hadoop 2.7 tar.
for how to setup the env , please use the following video in the youtube:-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t63PS3kiTTQ

You need to change the path to point to the correct spark directory you are using.

Comment: thanks bro but it got resolved just some permission request error  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42290821/7572545

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve using- chmod 777 /tmp/hive