# PySpark Installation - Failed to find Spark jars directory

Tags: java, python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having a lot of problems with Spark on **Windows**. So explaining the error:

There are a lot of tutorial to install and solve many issues, however I've been trying for hours and still can't make it work.

I have **Java 8**, which I have at `System Path`

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

I also have **Python 2.7 with Anaconda 4.4**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Spark\python\dist>python -V
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
```

Just in case, I do have **Scale**, **SBT** and **GOW**.

```
C:\>scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL

C:\>gow -version
Gow 0.8.0 - The lightweight alternative to Cygwin

C:\>sbt
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.15
```

So getting to the installation:

1. Firstly I downloaded [Spark 2.1.1](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) with package type **Pre-build for Apache Hadoop 2.7 and later**
2. I extract it on a certain Folder, say `C:\Programs\Spark`
3. On the *Python Folder*, I ran `python setup.py sdist`, that should make suitable tgz file for `pip`, which it did.
4. Going into `dist`, I ran `pip install NAME_OF_PACKAGE.tgz`. That did install it, because if `conda list`:

   ```
   C:\>conda list
   # packages in environment at C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2:
   #
   ...
   pyspark                   2.1.1+hadoop2.7           <pip>
   ...
   ```

   I did have some doubts, so I went to Anaconda's `Scripts` and `site-packages`. Both had what I expected, In Scripts there are `pyspark` `spark-shell` and so on. The `pyspark` folder at `site-packages` also has everything from **jars folder** to its own **bin folder** that also has  the scripts above.
5. About the hadoop, I did download **winutils.exe** and paste it on the `Spark's bin folder` which make it also be at the `python's pyspark's bin folder`.
6. With that in mind, I did import pyspark without a problem:

   ```
   C:\Users\Rolando Casanueva>python
   Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
   Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
   >>> import pyspark
   >>>
   ```

---

**FIRST QUESTION: Do I have to paste winutils.exe also at python's Scripts Folder?**

Going to main situation, the problem occurs when using `pyspark` and it raise this exception.

```
C:\Users\Rolando Casanueva>python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import pyspark
>>> pyspark.SparkContext()
C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyspark
"Files" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, 
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Failed to find Spark jars directory.
You need to build Spark before running this program.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 259, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 96, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
>>>
```

- I did install spark in local mode [StackOverFlow Answer to: How to set up Spark on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38735202/7351538)
- I did install spark like this **Youtube Tutorial**

*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omlwDosMGVk*

- I did install spark as a jupyter complement

*https://mas-dse.github.io/DSE230/installation/windows/*

- And finally I tried as above.

Same error shows on every installation.

**SECOND QUESTION: How to solve this issue?**

**EXTRA QUESTION: Any other recommendation to install it?**

Comment: I did solved the issue by using the non-space name of folder at Environ Path. In order to know this names, I look at them by running `dir /X`, which provides the short name for folders with spaces.