# Failed to find Spark jars directory. You need to build Spark before running this program

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I'm trying to install spark on windows 10 but I have an error while I try to run pyspark.

> Failed to find Spark jars directory. You need to build Spark before running this program.

I've followed the steps indicated [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715763/pyspark-installation-failed-to-find-spark-jars-directory?answertab=oldest#tab-top) until the step 4.

I went to Anaconda's Scripts and site-packages. In Scripts there are pyspark spark-shell and so on, BUT the pyspark folder at site-packages doesn't have neither the jars folder or its own bin folder.

Where are the jars?

Comment: Did you set your environment variables correctly? SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME as your spark installation directory and add $SPARK_HOME\bin to PATH

Comment: Hi MaFF, I set my environment variables, and they indicates the bin folder that contains each program.

Answer (score -2):

One of the causes of this error is that while settings the path Spark_home path may contain spaces like "C:/Users//apache spark/bin"

Just remove the spaces or change to another directory.