# Why do we need a virtual machine to install and use Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Big Data ecosystem. I am trying to install Apache Spark but the tutorials I found online ask me to first install a virtual machine. Cana someone please explain why I need a VM on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Spark uses Java. Java runs on all Operating Systems.

---

Tutorials might use the Hortonworks or Cloudera VMs because everything is *pre-configured*, but that is just an optimization that you could do on your own OS.

[How to set up Spark on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481325/how-to-set-up-spark-on-windows)

Comment: Hi cricket_007, I am new to spark and most of the tutorials I found online use either Hortonworks or cloudera, but now I understand the reason why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *requirement* to Apache Spark that you run it on a virtual machine. You can run it perfectly fine on your own computer locally. However normally when you are running software such as Apache Spark, you are processing huge amounts of data, and in doing so need to run large amounts of instances of the software in clusters. This type of requirement, which is an effect of having large data-sets means that it makes more sense to run them on virtual machines, which you can have several of on a single server, instead of one instance per physical server.

Comment: Hi Rietty, Thank you for explaining the reasoning behind it. I am new to Spark and  I feel like I have a better understanding now. Thanks again, Arun.

Comment: @Arunkumar mark an answer as expected if it answered the question (green checkmark)